Difficulty understanding the definition of the absolute value
I have some difficulty understanding this absolute value definition I got and that I need to use it to prove some things:$$|x|:=\begin{cases} 
x & \text{if } x \geq 0 \\
-x & \text{if } x < 0
\end{cases}$$
I am unsure what the definition is trying to tell me because for me this tells me if x bigger equal to zero, we have $x$ and if $x$ is smaller than zero, we have negative. But what I do not understand at this moment is how it correlates with absolute values. I think it is because for me absolute values are the difference from a negative number to $0$ or from zero to a positive number and that difference or rather distance, I would say would be a positive number. I apologize if I think with intuition too much and I am grateful for any help I can get.

Did you try to compute for example $|-3|$ using this definition?

If $x$ is a real number, then the absolute value simply makes it positive (or zero is $x$ is zero). Hence, if $x$ is smaller than zero, multiplying it by -1 gives a positive. Yet if $x$ is already positive, then we can leave it as is.

The minus might make $-x$ look like a negative number, but for $x<0$, the number $-x$ is in fact positive. Try graphing $y=-x$ on Desmos.

Thank you guys I did not realize that because x is a negative number -x will turn it into x thank you for helping me out.

No, $x$ being negatives doesn't "turn $-x$ into $x.$" It means that $-x$ is positive.

@ThomasAndrews I am not sure if I misunderstood the explanations now or used the incorrect wording so I will try to do the $|-3|$
$|-3|= -(-3) = 3$ is this the correct understanding or is the concept still not clear to me and it was more than misphrasing?
